# Cypress: How to know if element is visible or not in using If condition and xpath?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, e2e-testing

[Cypress: How to know if element is visible or not in using If condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57737783/cypress-how-to-know-if-element-is-visible-or-not-in-using-if-condition/71779724?noredirect=1#comment126857166_71779724)

The answer of the above question works perfectly for CSS selectors. The answer is

```
cy.get("body").then($body => {
    if ($body.find("selector_for_your_button").length > 0) {   
    //evaluates as true if button exists at all
        cy.get("selector_for_your_button']").then($header => {
          if ($header.is(':visible')){
            //you get here only if button EXISTS and is VISIBLE
          } else {
            //you get here only if button EXISTS but is INVISIBLE
          }
        });
    } else {
       //you get here if the button DOESN'T EXIST
       assert.isOk('everything','everything is OK');
    }
});
```

I want to achieve something similar but for XPath. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the xpath directly with the `find` command?

Comment: Conditional testing can lead to hassles to debugging, maintenance, and chance for false positives. Be careful out there.

Comment: @AlapanDas Yes I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XPath you can use `count()`

```js
cy.xpath(`count(//*[@class="${selector}"])`)
  .then(count => {
    if (count > 0) {
      cy.xpath(`//*[@class="${selector}"]`)  // repeat without count
        .click()
    } else {

    }
  })
```

But I think @jjhelguero's warning still applies. There isn't any retry with conditional testing, so you are losing the biggest advantage of Cypress - reducing flakiness in your tests.